# How do I use Active Record to get these records via the associations in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, instance-variables

I have the @user variable, and i have resources table, and then I have a favorites table which is merely user_id and resource_id

`@user.resources.each` works obviously

`@user.favorites.first.resource` works fine, except i want all of the resources.

`@user.favorites.resources` does not work

resource.rb

```
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :resource_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :resource_tags
```

user.rb

```
  has_many :resources
  has_many :favorites
```

favorite.rb

```
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :user
```

Comment: Could you post your models? Specifically looking for a `has_many` relationship between favorites and resources and/or a `has_many :through` connecting users to resources through favorites.

Comment: To make sure I understand, a user has many resources, but some of those resources are their favorites, which is defined through the favorites table.  If that's the case, when what you are really saying is that a user has_many :favorite_resources through favorites.  If you defined that explicitly, then you'd just need to call @user.favorite_resources...

Comment: hmm, so which part of my model is wrong? i would need to add a new table? everything from my model (sans validations etc) is above. each user can submit many resources, but can also favorite any given resource, then view their profile page to see their favorited resources as well as submitted resources. i have the @user.resources working, but the favorites is whats the problem. given by what you said maybe my model is wrong, although im new to this and im not sure what to change, i thought i did it right

Comment: by the way, why wouldnt it be user has_many :resources, :through => :favorites?

Comment: Your user already has_many :resources, so you can't also have has_many :resources, :through :favorites (you'd need to call it something else).  I think the only thing you need to change in your user model is the has_many through relationship for favorite_resources.  You don't need a new table, since you already have the favorites table.  If you haven't resolved this in the next 10 hours or so, I'll post a formal answer in the morning.

Comment: I would appreciate that much :) I have stared at this so much today that its not making sense anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@user.favorites.includes(:resource).collect(&:resource)
```

That should eager load the resource from all the User's favorites and then the collect should return them as an Array.

Comment: That worked great. Is there a more conventional way though that it should be done?

Comment: I think that is the most conventional ruby way ;-)